# passing x- and y-data as keyword arguments in matplotlib?

Tags: python, plot, ipython, matplotlib

Or, why doesn't

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xdata = numpy.array([1]), ydata = numpy.array(1), color = 'red', marker = 'o')
```

work?  c.f.

```
> In [21]: import numpy

> In [22]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

> In [23]: plt.plot(xdata = numpy.array([1]), ydata = numpy.array(1), color = 'red', marker = 'o')
> Out[23]: []

> In [24]: plt.plot([1],[1], color = 'red', marker = 'o')
> Out[24]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x108036890>]

> In [25]: plt.plot(1, 1, color = 'red', marker = 'o')
> Out[25]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1041024d0>]
```

Comment: Have you tried `plt.plot(xdata = [1], ydata = [1], color = 'red', marker = 'o')`? That matches your first working example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just to expand on what @Yann already said:

To understand why this happens, you need to understand a bit more about matplotlib's structure.  To allow "matlab-isms" like `plt.setp`, and to maintain compatibility with older versions of python, matplotlib avoid properties and relies heavily on getters and setters.  (`plot` is actually one of the most complex cases, simply due to all of the crazy forms of calling it supports.)

You can make a good argument that this is an outdated, unpythonic design, but that's beside the point.

What actually happens (for the simplest case of `plot(x, y, other=stuff)`) when you call `plot` is that a new `matplotlib.line.Line2D` object is created from the first two arguments, and then `matplotlib.line.Line2D.update(kwargs)` is called.

`update` basically does:

```
for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
    func = getattr(self, 'set_'+key)
    func(value)
```

I'm over-simplifying, but that's the basic idea.

Also the accepted keyword argument list is basically auto-generated from anything that has a `set_*`.  Because `Line2D` has `set_xdata` and `set_ydata` methods, they show up in the keyword argument list.

The point is, that the keyword arguments are never actually used until after most of the initialization of `Line2D`, and if you don't specify any arguments, `plot` won't initialize any `Line2D`'s.

You could consider this a bug, but I doubt it would be fixed. I don't think `xdata` and `ydata` were ever intended to be used as keyword arguments.

`set_xdata` and `set_ydata` are there to allow you to quickly update a `Line2D` instance instead of creating a new one (For animations, etc...).  They just happen to be allowed as keyword arguments due to the way matplotlib is set up.

Comment: Very helpful explanation.  Much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Who knows, but it appears a line is not created unless you define `x` and `y` arguments. `xdata` and `ydata` change the data of the line *only if it is created*, and it seems it is not created without the parameters. Try this:

```
plt.plot([0],[0],xdata = [1,2,3,4], #numpy.array([3,4]),
               ydata = [4,5,6,7], #numpy.array([3,4]), 
               color = 'red', 
               marker = 'o')
```

It works as I think you intend it to.

Comment: One will get "got multiple values for argument 'xdata'"
Apparently this is never going to work...