# Can a dictionary be used as a complete input to a matplotlib.pyplot?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib

I am setting up some code such that prior to plotting, the user can basically store all the plotting variables that they want to use in a dictionary, and these entries are stored for later use. The keys to the dictionary follow matplotlib.pyplot keyword syntax. An example of this dictionary would be something like this:

```
plot_info = {'title':'A neato title!',
             'x':[1,2,3,4],
             'y':[5,6,7,8],
             'grid':'on'}
```

How do I bring this dictionary into a plot command to execute the keys as arguments and the parameters as inputs to those arguments?

Thus far, I have attempted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plot_info = {'title':'A neato title!',
             'x':[1,2,3,4],
             'y':[5,6,7,8],
             'grid':'on'}
plt.plot(**plot_info)
```

Expecting this to do the trick. However, upon running the code, the figure pops up, but the figure is empty and everything is blank (runs without error but opens an empty figure).

I expect the output to display a plot whose title, x, and y values correspond to the dictionary values, and whose grid is on. Any idea why this plot would be blank?

For the record, I know that there are workarounds, and that this can be solved another way. However, I am curious as to why this is happening.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a dictionary to a function as keyword parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334655/passing-a-dictionary-to-a-function-as-keyword-parameters)

Comment: @Itay: That's not the relevant duplicate. I don't think matplotlib `plot` can work this way

Comment: Why would `plot` not work this way? Trying to increase my knowledge of how this works, and simply curious.

Comment: because even `plt.plot([1,2,3], [4,5,6], title='hello')` doesn't work

Comment: It's a known "bug"/limitation when using `plt.plot`, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979258/passing-x-and-y-data-as-keyword-arguments-in-matplotlib) to understand why.

Comment: Ok, makes sense now. Thought it was related to the way I was inputting the dictionary somehow, but glad to see its simply a limitation. Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do that with [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). The reason is that the signature for [`plt.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) reads:

```
def plot(*args, scalex=True, scaley=True, data=None, **kwargs)
```

The first parameter, `args`, which receives the data to plot, is a *var-positional* parameter. See the definition of [parameter](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter) from the glossary:

> **parameter**
>
> A named entity in a [function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-function) (or method) definition that specifies an [argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) (or in some cases, arguments) that the function can accept. There are five kinds of parameter:
>
> *positional-or-keyword*: specifies an argument that can be passed either [positionally](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) or as a [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument). This is the default kind of parameter, for example foo and bar in the following:
>
> ```
> def func(foo, bar=None): ...
> ```
>
> *positional-only*: specifies an argument that can be supplied only by position. Python has no syntax for defining positional-only parameters. However, some built-in functions have positional-only parameters (e.g. [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs)).
>
> *keyword-only*: specifies an argument that can be supplied only by keyword. Keyword-only parameters can be defined by including a single var-positional parameter or bare `*` in the parameter list of the function definition before them, for example *kw_only1* and *kw_only2* in the following:
>
> ```
> def func(arg, *, kw_only1, kw_only2): ...
> ```
>
> *var-positional*: specifies that an arbitrary sequence of positional arguments can be provided (in addition to any positional arguments already accepted by other parameters). Such a parameter can be defined by prepending the parameter name with `*`, for example *args* in the following:
>
> ```
> def func(*args, **kwargs): ...
> ```
>
> *var-keyword*: specifies that arbitrarily many keyword arguments can be provided (in addition to any keyword arguments already accepted by other parameters). Such a parameter can be defined by prepending the parameter name with `**`, for example *kwargs* in the example above.
>
> Parameters can specify both optional and required arguments, as well as default values for some optional arguments.
>
> See also the [argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument) glossary entry, the FAQ question on [the difference between arguments and parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-argument-vs-parameter), the [`inspect.Parameter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Parameter) class, the [Function definitions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function) section, and [**PEP 362**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362).

You can only give arguments for *positional-or-keyword* or *keyword-only* parameters with a dictionary. The *var-positional* parameter `args` is neither of those, so it cannot be filled anyhow.

By the way, about the definition above for *positional-only* parameters, a proper syntax for them has been accepted in [**PEP 570**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0570/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't think what you are asking is possible. [`plt.plot()` doesn't have `grid` or `title` arguments](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). Instead these arguments would be fed to [`plt` itself](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html?highlight=pyplot#module-matplotlib.pyplot)! You would need several lines of code for that (since they are different methods of a `plt` object) like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4],
         [5, 6, 7, 8])

plt.grid(True)
plt.title('A neato title!')

plt.show()
```

To make a valid script. I'm not sure how your intended solution is easier/more beautiful than the built in functionality, since you still have to specify the arguments anyways. If you are trying to implement defaults, perhaps a function would do the trick (you could expand this example to unpack a dictionary too):

```
def plot_my_data(x=(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 y=(5, 6, 7, 8),
                 grid_flag=True,
                 title='A neato title!'):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.grid(grid_flag)
    plt.title(title)
```

Where now a simple

```
plot_my_data()
plt.show()
```

Yields your expected

[image: output graph]

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [Reedinationer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56153825/565489) is already a good start, I would perhaps suggest creating a class instead, like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class CustomPlot(object):
    """docstring for CustomPlot"""
    def __init__(self, plot_dict):
        super(CustomPlot, self).__init__()
        self.plot_dict = plot_dict
        ## you should also include some kind of "validation" here
        ## which verifies the plot_dict key:value pairs 
        self.make_plot()
        plt.show()

    def make_plot(self):
        fig,ax=plt.subplots()
        for k,v in self.plot_dict.items():
            if isinstance(v,dict):
                print(k)
                if k=='plot':
                    eval('plt.plot({x},{y})'.format(**v))
            else:
                print(v)
                eval('plt.{0}("{1}")'.format(k,v) )

plot_info = {
    'title':'A neato title!',
    'plot':{    
        'x':[1,2,3,4],
        'y':[5,6,7,8],
    },
    'grid':'True'
}

p=CustomPlot(plot_info)
```

**Note:** I am using `eval()` here, which is not really a clean way to do this. It would require, that you **properly validate the dictionary** before you hand it over to `eval()`, and really, really, test this. In your exemplary input, you e.g. suggested to call `plt.plot()` with an argument `title`, which is *not following* `matplotlib.pyplot` keyword syntax, as you initially implied. This is a mistake that might also happen to your potential users, and you need to accommodate for this (i.e. make your own error handling). It might be better to create e.g. a dictionary of allowed function calls and expected types and then use this for validation.

Also, such a class would only *be the start*, you should next consider defining additional helper functions like `def loads_data()`, `def store_dict()`, and whatever else to have everything designed in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

its can be done, just keep the x & y first.

Example:

`plot_args = {'color':'black', 'marker':'.', 'linewidth':3, 'markersize':15, 'markerfacecolor':'white', 'markeredgecolor':'black', 'markeredgewidth':2} ax.plot(data[x],data[y],**plot_args)`
[image]